# Consuming SOAP Web Service with BinarySecurityToken using WCF, VB.NET and VS2015

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, soap

Best regards felas

I'm trying to access web service methods wich receive a signed XML as a parameter, using VB.NET and Framework 4.5. it happens that Web Service uses WS-Authentication with BinarySecurityToken schema, I managed to generate a resquest from SOAP UI and it works just fine, here's the request's XML:

base64binary-Token
         
            
               
                  
               
               
               
                  
                     
                        
                     
                  
                  
                  base64binary-DigestValue
               
            
            base64Binary-SignatureValue
            
               
                  
               
            
         
      
   
   
      
         
            HERE GOES XML DATA BETWEEN CDATA TAGS

I've been doing a lot of research and found that this can be done "easily" with WCF, but I can quite find how this WCF binding works and how I must pass my XML data so it can be wrapped into the SOAP envelope's body with propper security elements.

The code's I've examined look very complex for me since the just use base class that I can figure out where came from. I'd like to generate the code to cosume the WS without adding references but rather using http requests as this guy does here:

http://www2.sys-con.com/ITSG/virtualcd/WebServices/archives/0208/thota/index.html

I'd appreciate any help, and thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize about the XML code, so, here's the SOAP Message XML code

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dgi="http://dgi.gub.uy" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-B1784C762113654DB514508130204461">base64binary-Token</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
         <ds:Signature Id="SIG-B1784C762113654DB514508130206685" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
               <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                  <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dgi soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
               </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
               <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
               <ds:Reference URI="#id-B1784C762113654DB514508130206654">
                  <ds:Transforms>
                     <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                        <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="dgi" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                     </ds:Transform>
                  </ds:Transforms>
                  <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                  <ds:DigestValue>base64binary-DigestValue</ds:DigestValue>
               </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>base64Binary-SignatureValue</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-B1784C762113654DB514508130206312">
               <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-B1784C762113654DB514508130206463">
                  <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-B1784C762113654DB514508130204461" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
               </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
         </ds:Signature>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-B1784C762113654DB514508130206654" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <dgi:WS_eFactura.EFACRECEPCIONSOBRE>
         <dgi:Datain>
            <dgi:xmlData>HERE GOES XML DATA BETWEEN CDATA TAGS</dgi:xmlData>
         </dgi:Datain>
      </dgi:WS_eFactura.EFACRECEPCIONSOBRE>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```